# Mod_rewrite, trying to exclude images and css files

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to find a way to exclude image files and css files from my mod_rewrite permissions

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

#SecFilterInheritance Off
ErrorDocument 404 /fourohfour.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(myurl\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC,OR]  #my attempt at excluding

RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1&articleTopic=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Problem is with the exclusion line isn't quite accurate and I need help with it

If I go to any phpscript in my directory that isn't included in my .htaccess rewrite.. say for isntance www.myurl.com/articlelinks.php  I get redirected to this:

```
http://www./articlelinks.php
```

To complicate things further:

If I go to:
[http://www.myurl.com/articles/1/Dorsal+and+Volar+Intercalated+Segment+Instability+(DISI+and+VISI)](http://www.myurl.com/articles/1/Dorsal+and+Volar+Intercalated+Segment+Instability+%28DISI+and+VISI%29) the CSS files don't load

If I go to:

[http://www.myurl.com/articles.php?id=1&articleTopic=Dorsal+and+Volar+Intercalated+Segment+Instability+(DISI+and+VISI)](http://www.myurl.com/articles.php?id=1&articleTopic=Dorsal+and+Volar+Intercalated+Segment+Instability+%28DISI+and+VISI%29) the proper document is loaded with css and images

Please help?

Comment: use positive pattern. Negative pattern in your case is logically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `OR` flag in your condition, but there is no other condition after it, and that makes mod_rewrite think: `%{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|png|jpe?g|gif)$` or (anything). Try removing the OR

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|png|jpe?g|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1&articleTopic=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The reason your CSS isn't loading is probably because you're using relative URL paths in your document. Try either changing those links to absolute URL paths (starts with a `/`) or add this to the page's header:

```
<base href="/" />
```

The blank host problem, not sure why that's happening. Try adding this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
```

so that the rule looks like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(myurl\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```